# Delphi: how to set the length of a RTTI-accessed dynamic array using DynArraySetLength?

Tags: delphi, dynamic, arrays, rtti

I'd like to set the length of a dynamic array, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770242/how-to-set-array-length-with-delphi-2010-rtti). I have two classes TMyClass and the related TChildClass defined as

```
TChildClass = class
private
  FField1:  string;
  FField2:  string;
end;

TMyClass = class
private
  FField1:  TChildClass;
  FField2:  Array of TChildClass;
end;
```

The array augmentation is implemented as

```
var
  RContext:     TRttiContext;
  RType:        TRttiType;
  Val:          TValue;      // Contains the TMyClass instance
  RField:       TRttiField;  // A field in the TMyClass instance
  RElementType: TRttiType;   // The kind of elements in the dyn array
  DynArr:       TRttiDynamicArrayType;
  Value:        TValue;  // Holding an instance as referenced by an array element
  ArrPointer:   Pointer;
  ArrValue:     TValue;
  ArrLength:    LongInt;
  i:            integer;
begin
  RContext := TRTTIContext.Create;
  try
    RType := RContext.GetType(TMyClass.ClassInfo);
    Val := RType.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(RType.AsInstance.MetaclassType, []);
    RField := RType.GetField('FField2');
    if (RField.FieldType is TRttiDynamicArrayType) then begin 
      DynArr := (RField.FieldType as TRttiDynamicArrayType);
      RElementType := DynArr.ElementType;
      // Set the new length of the array
      ArrValue := RField.GetValue(Val.AsObject);
      ArrLength := 3;   // Three seems like a nice number
      ArrPointer := ArrValue.GetReferenceToRawData;
      DynArraySetLength(ArrPointer, ArrValue.TypeInfo, 1, @ArrLength);
      { TODO : Fix 'Index out of bounds' }
      WriteLn(ArrValue.IsArray, ' ', ArrValue.GetArrayLength);
      if RElementType.IsInstance then begin
        for i := 0 to ArrLength - 1 do begin
          Value := RElementType.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(RElementType.AsInstance.MetaclassType, []);
          ArrValue.SetArrayElement(i, Value);
          // This is just a test, so let's clean up immediatly
          Value.Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    ReadLn;
    Val.AsObject.Free;
  finally
    RContext.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Being new to D2010 RTTI, I suspected the error could depend on getting ArrValue from the class instance, but the subsequent `WriteLn` prints "TRUE", so I've ruled that out. Disappointingly, however, the same `WriteLn` reports that the size of ArrValue is 0, which is confirmed by the "Index out of bounds"-exception I get when trying to set any of the elements in the array (through `ArrValue.SetArrayElement(i, Value);`). Do anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? (Or perhaps there is a better way to do this?) TIA!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are kind of tricky to work with.  They're reference counted, and the following comment inside DynArraySetLength should shed some light on the problem:

// If the heap object isn't shared (ref count = 1), just resize it. Otherwise, we make a copy

Your object is holding one reference to it, and so is the TValue.  Also, GetReferenceToRawData gives you a pointer to the array.  You need to say `PPointer(GetReferenceToRawData)^` to get the actual array to pass to DynArraySetLength.

Once you've got that, you can resize it, but you're left with a copy.  Then you have to set it back onto the original array.

```
TValue.Make(@ArrPointer, dynArr.Handle, ArrValue);
RField.SetValue(val.AsObject, arrValue);
```

All in all, it's probably a lot simpler to just use a list instead of an array.  With D2010 you've got Generics.Collections available, which means you can make a `TList<TChildClass>` or `TObjectList<TChildClass>` and have all the benefits of a list class without losing type safety.

Comment: Thanks Mason, I guess I should've investigated that a little closer before asking... Anyways; I'm feeling pretty lazy lately, and TList and/or TObjectList is more convenient so I'll give it a spin. :) +1

Comment: I just needed the same and it works fine, but I get a memory leak each time I add a new element. Some ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: After some time of investigation, I found out that TValue.MakeWithoutCopy solves the problem of memory leaking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the array as a separate type:

```
TMyArray = array of TMyClass;
```

and use that.

From an old RTTI based XML serializer I know the general method that you use should work (D7..2009 tested):

```
procedure TXMLImpl.ReadArray(const Name: string; TypeInfo: TArrayInformation; Data: Pointer; IO: TParameterInputOutput);
var
  P: PChar;
  L, D: Integer;
  BT: TTypeInformation;
begin
  FArrayType := '';
  FArraySize := -1;
  ComplexTypePrefix(Name, '');
  try
    // Get the element type info.
    BT := TypeInfo.BaseType;
    if not Assigned(BT) then RaiseSerializationReadError; // Not a supported datatype!
    // Typecheck the array specifier.
    if (FArrayType <> '') and (FArrayType <> GetTypeName(BT)) then RaiseSerializationReadError;
    // Do we have a fixed size array or a dynamically sized array?
    L := FArraySize;
    if L >= 0 then begin
      // Set the array
      DynArraySetLength(PPointer(Data)^,TypeInfo.TypeInformation,1,@L);
      // And restore he elements
      D := TypeInfo.ElementSize;
      P := PPointer(Data)^;
      while L > 0 do begin
        ReadElement(''{ArrayItemName},BT,P,IO); // we allow any array item name.
        Inc(P,D);
        Dec(L);
      end;
    end else begin
      RaiseNotSupported;
    end;
  finally
    ComplexTypePostfix;
  end;
end;
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for the input Ritsaert. However, I think Mason pin-pointed the underlying problem.