# How to set value to a dynamic array using the rtti?

Tags: delphi, rtti, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying this way, however the size remains 0

```
  v := _RttiFld.GetValue(obj);
  P := v.GetReferenceToRawData;
  idx := 2; //to test
  DynArraySetLength(p,v.TypeInfo,1,@idx);
  Assert(_RttiFld.GetValue(obj).GetArrayLength > 0);
```

My field is a dynamic array of string

```
FMensage : array of string;
```

Comment: Do you really need to set the length of a dynamic array like this? You can use `SetLength` you know.

Comment: The answer given at this question: [how to set array length with delphi 2010 rtti](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1770571/576719) is wrong. I made a comment to notify the author.

Comment: And here is dupe number three: [Delphi: how to set the length of a RTTI-accessed dynamic array using DynArraySetLength?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2528732/576719).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why would anydbody use RTTI for this? Don't we have `SetLength`?

Comment: @Bogdan if I could use setlength have used. The complete code performs a process with generic data serialization using rtti